# Does every Latin square contain a diagonal in which no symbol appears thrice?

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

A *diagonal* of a [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) is a selection of n entries in which no two entries occur in the same row or column.  For example: the entries marked with an asterisk below form a diagonal.

```
1  2* 3  4
2  3  4  1*
3  4  1* 2
4* 1  2  3
```

**Theorem**:  Every Latin square contains a diagonal in which no symbol appears thrice (or more).

The asterisked diagonal in the above example is a diagonal in which no symbol appears thrice.

> **Problem**: Prove the above theorem.

This is quite a fun problem to solve, but there is a trap.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your definition of a diagonal isn't standard. When I was studying Latin squares 15 years ago, they all had two diagonals.

Comment: I think what you are calling "diagonals" are transversals (this might be interesting, but OT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problems_in_Latin_squares#Bounds_on_maximal_number_of_transversals_in_a_Latin_square ).

Comment: At Monash, we typically use "transversal" to mean a diagonal (as defined above) with no repeated symbols.  A common alternative is "transversal" instead of "diagonal" and "Latin transversal" instead of "transversal".

Answer (score 2):

You can do better- Cameron and Wanless showed that every latin square
possesses a diagonal in which no symbol appears more than twice.

> We also show that every Latin square contains a set of entries which meets each row and column exactly once while using no symbol more than twice.

For the paper, see [Covering radius for sets of permutations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V00-4FRKVKK-1&_user=10&_coverDate=04/06/2005&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=0346d4ec08678022aa368e2052bf2609&searchtype=a)

Comment: How is this "better"? "no symbol appears more than twice" is the same thing as "no symbol appears thrice or more", isn't it?

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/j.disc.2004.08.024](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2004.08.024) ([Zbl 1078.05001](https://zbmath.org/1078.05001)).